# remove the last "UNION ALL" in building up a sql query with foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, foreach

I want to build the following SQL query string using foreach loop

```
SELECT 'name' AS `field`. GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `name`  ORDER BY `name`) AS `value`
FROM product
UNION ALL
SELECT 'category' AS `field`. GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `category` ORDER BY `category`) AS `value`
FROM product
UNION ALL
SELECT 'year' AS `field`. GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `year` ORDER BY `year`) AS `value`
FROM product
```

The tricky part is that the following loop would result in an unnecessary "UNION ALL" in the last SELECT statement for `year`.

```
$selects = array("name"=>"Name","category"=>"Category","year"=>"Year");

$sql="";

foreach($selects as $select => $title)
{
  $sql .= "SELECT '".$select."' AS `field` , GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `".$select."`ORDER BY `".$select."` SEPARATOR '|' ) AS `value` FROM `product` UNION ALL";
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to remove the last UNION ALL from the last element (in this case,Year) in the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` in a variable. Initialize it as a empty string.

Prepend it on each iteration. Then assign `UNION ALL` to the variable.

```
$selects = array("name"=>"Name","category"=>"Category","year"=>"Year");

$sql="";
$union_all="";

foreach($selects as $select => $title)
{
  $sql .= $union_all . "SELECT '".$select."' AS `field` , GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `".$select."`ORDER BY `".$select."` SEPARATOR '|' ) AS `value` FROM `product`";
  $union_all=" UNION ALL ";
}
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 2):

In your foreach, make an array of your queries without the `UNION ALL`. Then:

```
$sql = implode(' UNION ALL ', $queries);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code may solve your problem.

```
$selects = array("name"=>"Name","category"=>"Category","year"=>"Year");

$sql="";

foreach($selects as $select => $title)
{
  $sql .= "SELECT '".$select."' AS `field` , GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `".$select."`ORDER BY `".$select."` SEPARATOR '|' ) AS `value` FROM `product`". ($select!='Year')?" UNION ALL":"";
}
```